# Calculate time duration from military time with ArcMap Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser, time

I have two text fields (STRTTIME, ENDTIME) which are are formatted as military time with leading zeros. For example, 0540, 1655.

I want to calculate a new field with the time duration as integers (in minutes).

How can I go about this using the Field Calculator in ArcMap?

Comment: What have you tried?  Please provide the function components as code blocks in your question. There will obviously be a modulus 100 in your calculations.

Comment: Are all those times within the same day? Or will there be any cases where start on day 1 and end is on the next day?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes, all the times are from the same day. Marcelo's code worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the times are from the same day, you can calculate the delta between the start time and the end time using the following Python function:

```
import datetime

def delta(start, end):
    start_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%H%M')
    end_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(end, '%H%M')
    return (end_dt - start_dt).seconds / 60
```

This function turns the strings into `datetime` objects so it can compute the delta between both times. Then it divides the number of seconds by 60 to return an integer with the minutes.

The date format is `%H%M` because:

> %H - Hour (24-hour)
>
> %M - Minute

You can run the function with the following expression: `delta(!STRTTIME!, !ENDTIME!)`

Comment: Thank you. Your code block works.

Comment: @Mercator https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

assuming they are the same day, you could just make a quick python function to calculate the time difference.

e.g.

Codeblock set to:

```
def func(start, end):
  time_diff = end - start
  return time_diff
```

and expression being:

`func(!STRTTIME!, !ENDTIME!)`

If it splits between days, you'll need some field to record how many days have passed.